# What happens if an item is modified in DynamoDB while SCANNING

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Suppose at t_0, we start a scanning of a DynamoDBTable. Suppose at t_1, an item in the table, call it i_0 that has not been iterated in the scanning, has been `Modified` to i_1. When the turn comes to the item in question, would the scanning return me i_0 or i_1?

Answer (score 1):

There is concept of consistency in AWS, which can be strong or eventual. By default DynamoDB is eventually consistent, so in this case it's possible to get old value.

You can force strong consistency read operation, but in any case one of operations - write or read - **will** be complete before another one, that's just how things work in this universe. Strong consistency ensures that whichever operation finished before this "strong" read will be reflected in the result.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadConsistency.html